# MySite: Custom links lost after "Change the look"

Tags: 2016, my-site, site-template, quick-links

SharePoint 2016 on premise migrated from 2013 approx 1 year ago.

After "**Change the look**" on MySite site collection on all personal sites user created custom links are lost. See red area in screenshot.

[image]

Before users were able to add custom links for their own site only by clicking "edit links" and adding them. The custom links were shown in the red area on the picture. This ability was lost by enabling a new look. How to re-enable custom links/"Edit Links"?

Have tried to "reset to site definition" without changes to the look and the missing feature. 
When clicking on "Apps" (site contents) the links are visible. So it seems to only affect default.aspx.

**After some digging and reading**

The "SharePoint 2016" mysite template does not support adding links to the left menu. The mysites migrated from SharePoint 2013 had this ability due to their old 2013 template which allowed custom links. 
*Is there a way to reenable the 2013 template for the mysites?*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth a try as an option to add links through "**Quick Launch**". Audience targeting for Quick Launch is only supported for site collections that have the "**Publishing Features enabled**".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Turns out it is a site template realted issue (2013 - 2016). Have edited my question with that information.